# How to import data from mysql to jtable through item in jcombobox in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

*Hello friends * I have a question related to netbeans 
i am working on a project and i want to know how can i import data from mysql to jtable by clicking on item name in jcombobox

As you can see in the image that i have a jcombobox and i want that when i select a item from jcombobox then the data in back end(mysql) should be imported in table
related to the item selected.

[image]

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jTeamActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    try {

        String data = jTeam.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String b = fName.getText();
        String c = jStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String aa = jTeamC.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:dist/Database/./h2database/recordDB", "test", "test");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "Select * from Students WHERE Team='" + data + "'";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        jTable3.getModel();

        DefaultTableModel a = (DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel();
        a.setRowCount(0);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String q = rs.getString("ID");
            String qq = rs.getString("NAME");
            String qqq = rs.getString("TEAM");
            String qqqq = rs.getString("STATUS");

            a.addRow(new Object[]{q, qq, qqq, qqqq});
        }

        String asa = jTeam.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if ("Select Team".equals(asa)) {
            Update1_table();
        } else {

        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CBL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CBL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

I don't know if this can help but this is how I did it in my project.

My jComboBox has Teams 01 to 12 in it. If for example "Team_01" was selected in the combobox, it will tell the system to get information from table Students.

```
String sql = "Select * from Students WHERE Team='" + data + "'";
```

and then It will display all the information about that team

```
                 String q = rs.getString("ID");
            String qq = rs.getString("NAME");
            String qqq = rs.getString("TEAM");
            String qqqq = rs.getString("STATUS");

            a.addRow(new Object[]{q, qq, qqq, qqqq});
```